# SQL: True/False/Null SUM of a Bit field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following table on `MS-SQL Server 2005`.

```
CREATE TABLE tblData(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                     FOOBAR1 BIT,
                     LOCATION VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO tblData (ID, FOOBAR1, LOCATION) 
VALUES (1,'True','Paris'), (2,'True','New York'), (3,'False','Paris')
     , (4,'False',NULL), (5,NULL,'Paris');
```

`tblCities` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblCities(cityName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO tblCities (cityName) 
VALUES ('Paris'), ('New York'), ('London');
```

I want to have aggregates for the bit `FOOBAR1` (True, False and NULL) So this is the SELECT statement that I've tried:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(tblCities.cityName) AS City
    ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes
    ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [No]
    ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoData
FROM tblCities 
LEFT JOIN tblData ON tblCities.cityName = tblData.LOCATION
GROUP BY tblCities.cityName
```

Results are the following:

```
City     | Yes | No | NoData |
LONDON   | 0   | 0  | 1      |
NEW YORK | 1   | 0  | 0      |
PARIS    | 1   | 1  | 1      |
```

Ideally, I want all five records in `tblData` to be accounted for in the SELECT statement:

```
City     | Yes | No | NoData |
LONDON   | 0   | 0  | 0      |
NEW YORK | 1   | 0  | 0      |
PARIS    | 1   | 1  | 1      |
NO DATA  | 0   | 1  | 0      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment:

> *example: INSERT INTO tblCities (cityName) VALUES ('Vancouver') ), that
>   city will also have ' 1 ' in the NoData column in tblData.*

If you want to handle `NO DATA` you have to change condition:

```
SELECT
     [City]   = ISNULL(UPPER(tc.cityName), 'NO DATA')
    ,[Yes]    = SUM(CASE WHEN td.FOOBAR1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,[No]     = SUM(CASE WHEN td.FOOBAR1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,[NoData] = SUM(CASE WHEN td.FOOBAR1 IS NULL 
                         AND td.LOCATION IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tblCities  tc
FULL JOIN tblData td
  ON tc.cityName = td.LOCATION
GROUP BY tc.cityName;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/GOT99470)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═════╦════╦════════╗
║   City    ║ Yes ║ No ║ NoData ║
╠═══════════╬═════╬════╬════════╣
║ NO DATA   ║   0 ║  1 ║      0 ║
║ LONDON    ║   0 ║  0 ║      0 ║
║ NEW YORK  ║   1 ║  0 ║      0 ║
║ PARIS     ║   1 ║  1 ║      1 ║
║ VANCOUVER ║   0 ║  0 ║      0 ║
╚═══════════╩═════╩════╩════════╝
```

Warning:

You should add artificial key for your `tblCities` table and join using it. Storing `CityName` in two tables is not best idea.

Comment: The implementation works. Thanks again @lad2025 and Paparazzi.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT isnull(UPPER(tblData.LOCATION),'NO CITY')
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 1     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [No]
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoData
FROM tblData 
GROUP BY isnull(tblData.LOCATION,'NO CITY')  

SELECT isnull(tblCities.cityName, isnull(tblData.LOCATION,'No City'))
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 1     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 = 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [No]
      ,SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoData
FROM          tblCities 
FULL OUT JOIN tblData 
               ON tblCities.cityName = tblData.LOCATION
GROUP BY isnull(tblCities.cityName, isnull(tblData.LOCATION,'No City'))
```

Comment: A JOIN statement was left out, my friend.

Comment: @JR.sc EXACTLY  - did you try this?

Comment: I did, and I received:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'` error

Comment: That ought to be:
`GROUP BY isnull(UPPER(tblData.LOCATION),'NO CITY')`

Comment: That comes close to what I want. I still would like to see the `LONDON` row.

Comment: Then expand it into a full outer and you will do in isnull on the city

Comment: London is showing ' 1 ' in the NoData column. Everything else is correct.

Comment: SE is not a code generation service.  Maybe work that out yourself.  You need an and in the case statement.

Comment: I will get back to this on Monday. I wonder if I need a combination of `SELECT INTO` and `COUNT` to insert a column, instead of `SUM (CASE WHEN tblData.FOOBAR1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoData` to come up with a value for the row.
I notice that if another city is included (example: `INSERT INTO tblCities (cityName) VALUES ('Vancouver')` ), that city will also have ' 1 ' in the NoData column in tblData.